# Install Qt Framework on Raspberry pi 2 B+ on Windows 10 IoT

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot, qt

Qt embedded system is very useful in this topic but it is not open source, it has a price for every year and it isn't cheap.

Windows 10 IoT is awesome OS, with PowerShell you can start OS with a specific application but is there any way to install Qt framework and run Qt application at Windows 10 IoT? I tried from remote but it has to be.appx files, Windows IoT doesn't support exe?

From [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181754/can-qt-be-used-for-developing-apps-for-windows-iot-core), you can install but how?

#### What I tried

First I found [this video](https://youtu.be/o5Xdt-j3hkA?t=28m26s) from QtWS2015. He explains how to convert and how to deploy to Raspberry Qt projects. 
I followed his path and downloaded winRT QT 5.6.0, it included ARM, and any other platform.

After that I ran qmake in the folder winrt_armv7_msvc2015 typing

```
qmake -tp vc CONFIG+=windeployqt
```

First I got error environment path. cmd says there isn't any path for uuidgen.exe. I didn't know what was that and I didn't know where was it. I searched and I found it in SDK Folder but I checked all SDK folder, I found only Win7.1a (in my path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin) and I added path in my cmd.

Everything was good from there. I opened project with Visual Studio, clicked **Remote Machine**, after one or two seconds I got this error:

[image]

I can see Qt Logo in Raspberry Pi monitor but always one or second later get this error.

I searched and I found this solution, **some application doesn't work 10.0.10540, maybe try 10.0.10240** and formatted and installed that version but result is the same I get same error.

Comment: I dont see any support for Windows IoT on the QT website. It may be possible to run it on IoT Enterprise, but that requires an Intel board.

Answer (score 1):

You don't install the complete Qt toolset on the target , but on your development machine .

- Install [Qt](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2) and Visual Studio on your desktop machine.
- Read this guide : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/winrt-support.html

Comment: there is so much information in the air. Should i look at "Building Qt 5 on Windows 8 WinRT" part ? 
Can you link any example for that ?

Comment: Sorry , i had added the wrong link. Edited it now.

Comment: okey thank you , ill try until morning , if i can , i let you know

Comment: i updated my post